# How to scrapy these data's from the website?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Here's an example: [http://www.cincinnati.com/story/money/2016/11/26/see-which-companies-16-deloitte-100/94441104/][1]

Ideally like to see a neatly crawled and extracted output data array with the following fields:

- Company Name
- 2016 Rank
- 2015 Rank
- Years in Business
- Business Description
- Website
- 2015 Revenues
- 2014 Revenues
- HQ City
- Year Founded
- Employees
- Is family owned?

from each of the specific company data pages.I'm purely beginner to scrapy i want know how to extract links automatically. Here in this code i'm feeding it manual. Can anyone help me here.

```
import scrapy
from spy.items import SpyItem

from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ProjectSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "project"
    allowed_domains = ["cincinnati.com/story/money/2016/11/26/see-which-companies-16-deloitte-100/94441104/"]
    start_urls = [100Links in here]



def parse(self, response):
            item = SpyItem()
            item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="overlay"]/div[2]/article/div[3]/p[1]/strong/text()').extract()
            item['Business'] =response.xpath('//*[@id="overlay"]/div[2]/article/div[3]/p[4]/text()').extract()
            item['website'] =response.xpath('//p[5]/a/text()').extract()
        item['Ranking']=response.xpath('//*[@id="overlay"]/div[2]/article/div[3]/p[2]/text()[1]').extract()
        item['HQ']=response.css('p:nth-child(12)::text').extract()
        item['Revenue2015']=response.xpath('//*[@id="overlay"]/div[2]/article/div[3]/p[7]/text()').extract()
        item['Revenue2014']=response.css('p:nth-child(10)::text').extract()
        item['YearFounded']=response.xpath('//p[11]/text()').extract().encode('utf-8')
        item['Employees']=response.xpath('//article/div[3]/p[12]/text()').extract()
        item['FamilyOwned']=response.xpath('//*[@id="overlay"]/div[2]/article/div[3]/p[13]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Show us codes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are at least two issues with your code.

1. `allowed_domain` has to be a domain. Not more.
2. You use a `CrawlSpider` that is meant to be used with `Rules`. You don't have any rules.

In the following there is some tested code as starting point:

```py
import scrapy

class ProjectItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    owned = scrapy.Field()

class ProjectSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "cin100"
    allowed_domains = ['cincinnati.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.cincinnati.com/story/money/2016/11/26/see-which-companies-16-deloitte-100/94441104/']

    def parse(self, response):

        # get selector for all 100 companies
        sel_companies = response.xpath('//p[contains(.,"Here are the companies")]/following-sibling::p/a')

        # create request for every single company detail page from href
        for sel_companie in sel_companies:
            href = sel_companie.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
            url = response.urljoin(href)
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_company_detail)
            yield request

    def parse_company_detail(self, response):

        # On detail page create item
        item = ProjectItem()
        # get detail information with specific XPath statements
        # e.g. title is the first paragraph
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[1]//text()').extract_first()
        # e.g. family owned has a label we can select
        item['owned'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"Family owned")]/text()').extract_first()
        # find clever XPaths for other fields ...
        # ...
        # Finally: yield the item
        yield item
```

Comment: item['Revenue2014'] ='$'+response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"2014")]/text()').extract_first().split('$')[1]                                             I'm getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' Can anyone here help me?